# Move all Columns if one row changes in height using Quasar

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm programming a Jeopardy game using Vue3 in combination with Quasar 2.11.6. I have a grid of `q-cards` and a header with an editable Text (`q-input`) representing the topic of the column, like here:
[image]
The Problem is that if the user edits the topic of a column into a longer text that would exceed one line, the text wraps and the cards of that particular column shift down, but not the other ones. My wish would be, that all cards of all column shift down instead of just one. So for the example in the image, I want all cards wo align with the one beneath "You gotta know this".
The Code that I'm running is:

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="category in categories" :key=category.id class="column no-wrap">
    <div class="row flex justify-center text-h4">
      <q-input borderless type="textarea" autogrow v-model="category.title" :input-style="{ fontSize: '35px', width: '270px', lineHeight: '35px'}"/>
    </div>
    <div v-for="question in category.questions" :key="question.id" class="row no-wrap">
      <q-card class="bg-teal-3 q-ma-sm"}">
      </q-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Initially I was expecting my wanted behaviour since I understood the rows and columns like in a table where a row would have the same hight across all columns.

I already tried to use a table with table-cells, which looked like a promising way of doing it, but I was not able to get it to work.
I would like to solve this problem in a "Quasar-way" but I would also appreciate an answere that uses CSS (or SCSS) styling.

Comment: Use Grid in the parent div, and it will make sure to maintain height throughout the row

Comment: @aarkaynegi You mean use grid in the first div of my code-example? How would I use the grid? In the div-class or in CSS? Thank you for the advice!